# Using same image and button style for multiple tab buttons

Tags: xaml, reference, styles, setter

I have a user control that contains a tab item with multiple tabs. Each tab contains a custom stack panel with identical buttons (add, update, delete). I am receiving a "specified element is already the logical child of another element. Disconnect it first" error. I'm not sure what to do to disconnect it as I already have the `x:Shared = "False"` element set.

Inside Grid.Resource:

```
<!--ButtonAddImage-->
<Image x:Key="ButtonAddImage"
       x:Shared="True">
    <Image.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
            <Setter Property="Source"
                    Value="add2_32.png" />
            <Setter Property="Stretch"
                    Value="Uniform" />
        </Style>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>


<!--ButtonAddStyle-->
<Style TargetType="Button"
       x:Key="ButtonAddStyle"
       x:Shared="False">
    <Setter Property="Content"
        Value="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ButtonAddImage}" />
    <Setter Property="Width"
            Value="32" />
    <Setter Property="Height"
            Value="22" />
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment"
            Value="Left" />
    <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment"
            Value="Center" />
</Style>
```

Inside Tab:

```
<Button  Style="{DynamicResource ResourceKey=ButtonAddStyle}"
         Name="gdSMSInfo_btnAddRecord"
         Click="gdSMSInfo_btnAddRecord_Click">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have x:Shared="False" for the button style, but x:Shared="True" for the image that you are using in the style.  Change the x:Shared on the image itself to False and it works for me.